# Mobile Responsive Logo

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to get the logo on the mobile version of my site to be centered (only the mobile not desktop). Please help.

*EDIT: When I add css to center align the logo, it does the desktop version of the site and not the mobile version. I only want the mobile version to have the center alignment of the logo.*

```
<div class="container">
    <header class="header">
        <!-- Logo -->
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>">
                <?php
                    $logo              = get_theme_mod( 'logo_img', false );
                    $logo2x            = get_theme_mod( 'logo2x_img', false );
                    $logo_width_height = get_theme_mod( 'logo_width_height', '' );

                    if ( ! empty( $logo ) ) :
                ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $logo ); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ); ?>" srcset="<?php echo esc_attr( $logo ); ?><?php echo empty ( $logo2x ) ? '' : ', ' . esc_url( $logo2x ) . ' 2x'; ?>" class="img-responsive" <?php echo sanitize_text_field( $logo_width_height ); ?> />
                <?php
                    else :
```

[image]

Comment: Hard to tell, can you please post your css and possibly a working code example here.

Comment: For more in-depth list of centering examples, see W3C's [recommendations](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html).